# java script html element scrape using a scrapy on phython 2.7.11 i get like these

Tags: python, scrapy, pycurl

```
[root@Imx8 craigslist_sample]# scrapy crawl spider
/root/Python-2.7.11/craigslist_sample/craigslist_sample/spiders/test.py:1: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.spider` is deprecated, use `scrapy.spiders` instead
  from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
/root/Python-2.7.11/craigslist_sample/craigslist_sample/spiders/test.py:6: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: craigslist_sample.spiders.test.MySpider inherits from deprecated class scrapy.spiders.BaseSpider, please inherit from scrapy.spiders.Spider. (warning only on first subclass, there may be others)
  class MySpider(BaseSpider):
2016-10-18 18:23:30 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.2.0 started (bot: craigslist_sample)
2016-10-18 18:23:30 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'craigslist_sample.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['craigslist_sample.spiders'], 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'BOT_NAME': 'craigslist_sample'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 142, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 88, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 149, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 57, in run
    self.crawler_process.crawl(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 162, in crawl
    crawler = self.create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 190, in create_crawler
    return self._create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 194, in _create_crawler
    spidercls = self.spider_loader.load(spidercls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 43, in load
    raise KeyError("Spider not found: {}".format(spider_name))
KeyError: 'Spider not found: spider'
```

Comment: What's your output for `scrapy list`? Then run `scrapy crawl <spidername>`, where `<spidername>` is one of the the names you got from `scrapy list`

Answer (score 0):

your should set name='spider' in craigslist_sample/craigslist_sample/spiders/test.py

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'spider'
    def parse(self,response):
        #....
```